# Correcting use-effect to re-render react component only once upon value loading from API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, next.js, use-effect

I am having trouble with a content loading issue with my react/next.js app using hooks. I believe the problem is with my useEffect and the dependency. I would appreciate any unblockin assistance. The situation:

As you will see from the code below:

- In the useEffect:
- 'eventType' object loads from one API endpoint and is added to the corresponding state
- if eventType is a movie (has externalData key) then we load the movie object from another API endpoint based on the filmId (in externalData)
- so if eventType.externalData is not null then we set the movie state value to the content of the response data
- if movie state is true then we render the 'movie' code block
- else we render the 'non-movie' code block

The issue:

- For some reason the movie information is not coming back fast enough from the API call, so when given the choice of what to render, the app renders the non-movie block
- In order to counteract this, I added [movie] to the dependencies for the useEffect. This works, but leads to infinite reload hell.

My question:
How can I make sure that the reload is triggered only once when the movie data loads and not infinitely?

```
function EventDetailPage(props) {
    const router = useRouter();

    const slug = router.query.slug;
    const cinemaId = router.query.cinemaId;
    const date = slug[0];
    const eventTypeId = slug[1];
    const {locale} = useRouter();

    const [eventType, setEventType] = useState(null);
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);
    const [personData, setPersonData] = useState(null);

    const {user} = useUserStore();

    const setupEventDetailPageWithData = async () => {
        try {
            const eventType = await getEventTypeByCinemaIdAndDate(cinemaId, date, eventTypeId);
            setEventType(eventType);
            console.log('eventType state:', eventType);

            if (!user){
                const personDataResponse = await fetchPersonData();
                setPersonData(personDataResponse);
            }

            if (eventType.events[0].userId === personData.userId){
                console.log("Event initiator id:", eventType.events[0].userId);
                setIsInitiator(true);
            }


            if (eventType.externalData) {
                const movie = await getMovieById(eventType.externalData.filmId);
                setMovie(movie);
            } else {
            }


        } catch (error) {
            // handle error
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {

        setupEventDetailPageWithData();

    }, [movie]);


    if (!eventType) {
        return (
            <>
                <LoadingAnimation/>
            </>
        );
    }

if (movie) {
    return ( <div> movie code </div> )
        
    } else {
    return ( <div> non-movie code </div> )
    
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that your `setupEventDetailPageWithData` is trying to do too many things at the same time. I'd suggest you separate the logic into different `useEffect`s/functions.

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves! I will try that. How would you suggest seperating them? Do you think each if statement be in a seperate useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

you can do somethings like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  //call api and set your state
},[])
```

or better practise like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  //call your api and set your state
},[setMovie])
```

Comment: Thanks @amirhosein! But is that different from the code that I already have? Or do you think I need to have a useEffect each for every API call?